# Zoom in and cut images in Twenty Seventeen header image

Tags: amazon

I'm using Theme Twenty-seven years and am trying to control the behavior of header images / mediums for different screen resolutions / sizes.

The standard seems to only crop the image and change the aspect ratio when changing the screen to a lower resolution. Instead I want it to "zoom in", keeping the aspect ratio the same as the full screen layout. This seems to be the standard for image control panels.

I've played with a bunch of css setups, but can not seem to find the right one ...

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this issue better to use javascript library imageScale();

Different options available in this(fill, best-fill, best-fit, best-fit-down).

You have to just include js file. then after using the following format for the image.

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="scale" data-scale="best-fit-down" data-align="center" src="img/example.jpg">
</div>
```

Now add this JavaScript code to your page.

```
$(function() {
   $("img.scale").imageScale();
});
```

The second option is to use another javascript imagefill.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="myawesomeimage" />
</div>


$('.container').imagefill(); 
  // image stretches to fill container
```

for more [imageScale](https://github.com/gestixi/image-scale)  | [imageFill](https://github.com/johnpolacek/imagefill.js/)